# Adding versioning to a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, version

I have a table where each record has a `Value`, a `VersionEffective` and a `VersionExpiration` column. Currently, the `VersionEffective` column is filled out correctly, but the `VersionExpiration` column is defaulted to `'9999-12-31'`. For records with the same value, only the record with the latest `VersionEffective` should not be expired. The rest should be. Specifically, when a new record is inserted, if there was an active record previously with the same value, that record will be expired with its `VersionExpiration` equivalent to the new record's `VersionEffective`. I have a stored proc to correctly set the `VersionEffective`/`VersionExpiration` as they're inserted, but I need to go back and retroactively update the `VersionExpiration` fields for the old records.

What I'm currently thinking is something similar to the following:

```
  UPDATE fubarTable as t
     SET t.VersionExpiration = ( 
               SELECT TOP 1 VersionEffective
                 FROM fubarTable as f
                WHERE t.Value = f.Value
             ORDER BY VersionEffective DESC
         )
       ;
```

But, this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: so are you asking how to make the above statement work? or asking for a different implementation of your versioning system?

Comment: I'm looking for a different implementation, since I'm fairly sure that what I proposed isn't remotely close to what would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it for you with your current setup:

```
UPDATE t
 SET t.VersionExpiration = ( 
       SELECT TOP 1 VersionEffective
         FROM fubarTable as f
        WHERE t.Value = f.Value and f.VersionEffective > t.VersionEffective
     ORDER BY VersionEffective
 )

 FROM fubarTable t
 where t.VersionEffective <> ( Select MAX(VersionEffective) from fubarTable where Value = t.Value)
```

Comment: For all but 3 records, this set the VersionExpiration for all the records to the highest VersionEffective in the table.

Comment: I've updated the query as I think I misunderstood your table structure and how the records are structured, that it is records with the same value.  I was expecting the value to change

Comment: Updated again to filter out the last record from being updated as well since you want to leave that at 9999-12-31 I believe.

Comment: Sorry, on further inspection, that's not quite correct. It works great for values that only have 2 records, but for values with >2 records, the versionExpiration for the old records is also set to the versionEffective of the most recent record, when it should be set to the versionEffective of the record that would have caused it to become expired. If that makes sense.

Comment: That did it. Much appreciation for the help.